# How to filter one array of strings based on the contains of a second array of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, filter

## Solved, i just can't select my own answer

I have an array that gets loaded from `JSON` into an `NSMutableArray`. One of the entries, `AllowedTo`, has a value of `New York, Florida`

I also have a second array that comes in from a separate `JSON` to a new `NSMutableArray` and using this array, I populate a `UITableView`:

Using the first array, I want to hide any cell that doesn't match in the second array. For example, the end result will (using the image posted above) only have 3 cells (GRAND TOTAL, NEW YORK, FLORIDA) and the rest (JUNIORS, FOODNATION, etc...) will be hidden.

Comment: It seems your question is about working with arrays, not about UITableView, is it? If so please reformulate your question - delete anything that is not needed (like table view) and clarify what do you need.

Comment: if you mean the tags, i used whatever was recommended. ill remove it as i see fit. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could do it using the [filter function](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/).

```
    let arrayOne = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    let arrayTwo = ["one", "two", "three"]


    let filteredArray = arrayOne.filter({ arrayTwo.contains($0)})

    print("filteredArray: \(filteredArray)")
```

I would then create a function for this so you can call it as needed without altering your original arrays.

```
func filterDataSource(arrayOne: [String], arrayTwo: [String]) -> [String] {

    let filteredArray = arrayOne.filter({ arrayTwo.contains($0)})

    return filteredArray

}
```

---

EDIT

The same functionality in Objective-C, there are more elegant ways of doing it, but I am a bit rusty :)

```
NSArray *arrayOne = @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five"];
NSArray *arrayTwo = @[@"one", @"two"];


NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

for (NSString *string in arrayOne) {
    for (NSString *filterString in arrayTwo) {

        if ([string isEqualToString:filterString]) {
            [filteredArray addObject:string];
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Comment: any chance of an obj-c version. i have yet to look into swift

Comment: one small issue, mostly my fault, both mutable array are dictionaries. how would i get the string of an array in a dictionary for example, arrayOne.AllowedTo......edit: i brainfarted. i know this one lol. thanks for your help. ill mark your answer once i get it working

Answer (score 0):

You could also use sets:

```
NSMutableSet *dataToShow = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:yourFirstArray];
NSSet *other = [NSSet setWithArray:yourSecondArray];
[dataToShow intersectSet:other];
```

Now "dataToShow" has only the items that exist in both of your arrays.

EDIT

For example:

Array1 has "1", "2", 3", "4"

Array2 has "1", "4", "5"

Set1 will have Array1's elements, but probably different order: "2", "4", "3", "1

Same for Set2: "4", 1", "5"

The intersected set, the "dateToShow", would then have elements "1" and "4" because those are the only ones present in both sets.

However, the order can't be guaranteed, so if that's important to you...I suggest [dataToShow.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator....];

Comment: what i want to do is, if arrayOne.AllowedTo = arrayTwo.EntityName, add that to newArray and populate the table with newArray. can that be done with Sets? I've never used them before

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your data structure, but a Set is sort of like an array except it's unordered and the items in it are unique.  So I was suggesting that you make a set for each of the 2 arrays and then leverage the intersect feature to get the elements in common.  You can then get the intersected set's "allObjects" array for your table, although you may need to re-sort it.

Answer (score 0):

so, i was looking at this the wrong way. my intent was to parse a JSON in to an array and then strip out what i dont need. when it was much more simpler to just fill the array with what i want to show. at the end of my JSON parser, i added this

```
if ([AllowedTo containsString:newEstNet.EntityName]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ displayed", newEstNet.EntityName);
    [listOfEstNetGrand addObject:newEstNet];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ not displayed", newEstNet.EntityName);
    // dont add the object to the array
}
```